# post two dimensional array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to post and receive a two dimensional array, but I can't get it to work.

Could you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
$items[] = array(
  'pid' => $pid
  , 'qty' => $product_qty
);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="items[]" id="pid" />
```

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $row) {
  $pid = $row['pid'];
  $product_qty = $row['qty'];
}
```

Comment: Do `print_r($_POST);` and you see the structure of your array and with which keys you can access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code in a way like this:

```
$items = array('pid' => $pid, 'qty' => $product_qty);
foreach( $items as $key => $val )
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="items['.$key.']" value="'.$val.'" id="'.$key.'" />';
}
```

In your original code, `$items[]` add a new item to array `$items`.

Also, HTML doesn't interpret php variables, so your `<input name="items[]"` will produce `$_POST[items][0]` with an empty value.

Comment: Thanks! but what do i do on the receiving end?

Comment: You will receive yr example's expected `$POST` => `$_POST['items']['pid']` etc... Also note that in my example there is `id` attribute, as per yr code, but the `id` attribute is not sent with `$_POST`

Comment: The submitting and receiving works but when i remove the brackets after $items the array displays two times the last loop :(

Comment: I don't understand. What loop? `$items` loop or `$_POST` loop?

Comment: the $items loop, sorry i forgot to mention $items[] = array('pid' => $pid, 'qty' => $product_qty);    is in a foreach loop

Comment: It is not possible. It will display two `<input>`, one for `pid`, another for `qty`. Otherwise, you have different code, or the problem is caused by other part of code.

Comment: Thanks, i think the fault is in my foreach loop, because $items only contains the latest item array that went trough the loop

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
$myarr = array( 'pid' => array($pid), 'qty' => array($product_qty));
```